# No Default Web Site or Application Pools shown under server in IIS 8.5 new installation

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have a newly installed Windows Server 2012 and I have installed IIS. When I open the IIS manager the server is shown there, but there are no nodes under the server for application pools or Default Web Site. What have I done wrong? I have completely uninstalled IIS and re-installed it with the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case here, but for a similar situation I encountered on our systems it was simply a case of mismatching versions.

i.e. The server originally creating the shared config was Server 2012 with IIS 8.0, but the server attempting to access it and showing the symptoms displayed mentioned was Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.

Look in the event log after loading IIS Manager and you should see a load of errors indicating it's a missing module problem, likely down to versioning.